# Trying to highlight the closest numbers (over or under) to a specific number in a column

Tags: google-sheets

I have an NFL Pick'Em sheet and I'm trying to highlight the numbers closest (over or under) to a set number in a column.

Total points: in cell R4
Range of numbers: R5-R22

The following formula works in Excel for windows but not in my Google sheet.  Any help would be appreciated.

=ABS(R5-$R$4)=MIN(ABS($R$5:$R$22-$R$4))

Answer (score 0):

You need an Array Formula

=ABS(R5-$R$4)=MIN(ARRAYFORMULA(ABS($R$5:$R$22-$R$4)))